# selected values from MultiAutoCompleteTextView dropdown didn't display again in dropdown

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am using [MultiAutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MultiAutoCompleteTextView.html) from that i have an query that

when we select value from the dropdown of MultiAutoCompleteTextView, Can we remove this selected value from the dropdown until this value is not match in adapter.

e.g.

```
MultiAutoCompleteTextView mulitAutoCompleteTextView = new MultiAutoCompleteTextView(context);
mulitAutoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);
mulitAutoCompleteTextView.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());

String name[] = {sample, test, example};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, name);
mulitAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

if i select "sample" from the multiAutoCompleteTextView dropdown than again "sample" is not display in the dropdown when i type other word.

A MultiAutoCompleteTextView dropdown not show selected values. It display only 2 String "test" and "example"

Please tell me how can i implement.

Thank you,

Comment: what is your threshold?

Comment: type "e" in textview. and then see result.it display all three or not.?

Comment: it not display all three, it display only example

Comment: you said sample not display on list when you searched other word.. but you are wrong. because it cant display "sample" word because of threshold and search criteria...

Comment: See, If i select "sample" from dropdown this value set in EditText then after comma if i try again type "s" for select other value than selected value "sample" is not display in dropdown. it can display other values which start from "s" if no other values then dropdown  is not displaying

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31093/discussion-between-segi-and-krunal-shah)

Comment: come there in discussion chat.

Answer (score 0):

```
mulitAutoCompleteTextView.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
```

put this line after setadapter line.

Comment: Thanks, But still i am not getting result